# How to input in python multiple times, given 'n' inputs?

Tags: python-3.x

This code accepts BTC, ICX,..... inputs one at a time and i would to make accept multiple inputs and output multiple files with the same name as the input. How can i do it?

eg. ETH,ICX, ALG...

Edit: i would like to give n currencies.

```
from cryptocmd import CmcScraper

currency = input("enter currency:")
date_from = input("enter begining date")
date_to = input ("enter end date")

# initialise scraper with time interval

if date_from and date_to:
    scraper = CmcScraper(currency, date_from, date_to)
else:
    scraper = CmcScraper(currency)

# get raw data as list of list
headers, data = scraper.get_data()

# get data in a json format
json_data = scraper.get_data("json")

# export the data to csv
scraper.export("csv")

# get dataframe for the data
df = scraper.get_dataframe()
```

Comment: Do you want to perform this input/output loop "n" times until you want to exit, or do you want to give "n" currencies etc. and perform the script for each of inputs?

Comment: What you can do is put your entire code in a `while` loop as: `while(True): ... if currency=="": break` and break the loop if currency is empty

Comment: @bhagyesh-dudhediya  for example `if date_from and date_to:
................................... df = scraper.get_dataframe()  if currency=="": break`   ...... Dont i have to use a split function coz of the N inputs?

Comment: @Tzane Yes, "n" currencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to give multiple values in a single `input`, you can use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to separate each input and use a `for` loop to iterate over each one:

```
currency_n = input("enter currency:")
date_from = input("enter begining date")
date_to = input ("enter end date")

for currency in currency_n.split(" "):
    # initialise scraper with time interval

    if date_from and date_to:
        scraper = CmcScraper(currency, date_from, date_to)
    else:
        scraper = CmcScraper(currency)

    ...
```